# Unhashed password in PHP

Tags: php

how I can put my variable $passHash from register function  to login function
I need that cause I try to use password_verify() method which required my hash

I try additional got my hashe password from database and put to the password_verify() but it not working.

```
public function register($uname, $email, $pass) {  
 
    
    $passHash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sqlQuery="INSERT INTO UserData (userName, userEmail, userPassword) VALUES (:userName,:userEmail,:userPassword)";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $stmt->bindparam(':userName', $uname);
        $stmt->bindparam(':userEmail', $email);
        $stmt->bindparam(':userPassword', $passHash);
    
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return $stmt->error;
    }
}

public  function login($emailUser,$passUser){
    $sqlQuery= "SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE userEmail=? AND userPassword=? ";
    
    // $sqlQuery.Id;
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $stmt->execute([$emailUser, $passUser]);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); <-- NOT WORKING SO I try get hash variable from  register function 
    $checkPassword=password_verify($passUser,$result["userPassword"]);

    if($checkPassword==true){

        if($stmt->rowCount()==0){
            echo "err";
        }else{
    
            echo "success";
        }
    }else{

        echo 'bad pass';
    }


}
```

Comment: Your password will be hashed, so it will never match what is being sent from the form. Drop `AND userPassword=? `, and just use password_verify to match the existing password, if the user exists.

Comment: You misled yourself by called the database column `userPassword` when actually it is the `userPasswordHash`.

Comment: @aynber yeah it is wise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Steps to run a successful login attempt:

1. Collect the username/identifier from the login client.

   ```
   $emailUser = $_POST['email'];
   $passUser = $_POST['password'];
   ```
2. Send *only* that to the MySQL to retrieve *only* that row, including the hashed password and the row identifier.

   ```
   SELECT UserId, userPassword FROM UserData WHERE userEmail=?
   ```
3. Using PHP check the hashed password from the database matches the value given by the  user

   ```
   if(password_verify($passUser, $result['userPassword']){
      ...
   ```
4. allow access....

---

- **NEVER** send the password to MySQL, it's worthless.
- Use `$stmt->fetchAll();` to retrieve the data row
- It is bad practise to do `SELECT *`  instead you should select the columns you actually want to use.
- your `$stmt->rowCount()==0` clause will **always fail**, because it is after the password has been tested and passed, so remove this whole section.
- It is bad practise to tell people specifically their password has failed, as this can be used to fish for if someone has an email on this system. Instead state "Your email OR password are incorrect" so it can't so easily be established by 3rd parties if a certain persons email is on a system.